# Cannot open the device if it is a composite device (with two interfaces) using webUSB APIs

Tags: webusb

I am using Chrome browser v72.0.3626.109(Official Build)(32-bit) on Windows 10.

1. Trying to claim a USB interface of a vendor specific composite USB device with 1 interface that is vendor specific and the other DFU runtime interface that loads a winusb driver. 
   I have ensured, that the vendor specific driver is not loaded, yet

   > opening the device via webUSB API device.open() fails with code:18 (SecurityError: Access denied.)

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
      let button = document.getElementById('connect')

      button.addEventListener('click', async() => {
        let device
        const VENDOR_ID = 0x04xx
    const PRODUCT_ID = 0x6xxx

        try {
          device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
            filters: [{
          vendorId: VENDOR_ID,
          productId: PRODUCT_ID
            }]
          })

      await device.open(); //Begin a session
      await device.selectConfiguration(1); 
      await device.claimInterface(0); 
      await device.releaseInterface(0); 
      await device.close(); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
      await device.close()
  })
})
```

Other scenarios that I have tried...

2. My USB device comes up with only 1 interface (vendor specific bulk interface) and no drivers loaded. The device does not get listed in the device selection menu opened by requestDevice.
3. My USB device comes up with only 1 interface (DFU runtime interface) with winusb driver loaded. The device gets listed, opened and claim inteface can work using webUSB API.

Is there a restriction to list and open a vendor specific USB device using webUSB APIs? Anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The vendor specific interface can be opened with WebUSB but the WinUSB driver needs to be loaded against it. This is a requirement from the Windows API that the browser uses to open the device.